# Custom react hook useToggle in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I wrote custom hook for toggling booleand valuse:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useToggle(initialValue: boolean) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<boolean>(initialValue);

  const toggleValue = () => setValue(!value);

  return [value, toggleValue];
}
```

Then I use it like below:

```
 const [modalOpen, setModal] = useToggle(false);
```

But get errors:

> Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
>   ((() => void) & false) | ((() => void) & true)'.   Type '() => void'
>   is not assignable to type 'boolean | ((() => void) & false) | ((() =>
>   void) & true)'.
>       Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(() => void) & false'.
>         Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'false'.

Comment: I was just working on the same thing.  This is a great article https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-typeing-custom-hooks/   You need to return [value, toggleValue] as const or add a return type to the useToggle function do return a tuple not an array

Answer (score 5):

You might need to define the return type of your hook. It should look something like this.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useToggle(initialValue: boolean): [boolean, () => void] {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<boolean>(initialValue);

  const toggleValue = () => setValue(!value);

  return [value, toggleValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const {useRef, useState} = React;

function useToggle(initialState){
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialState);
  const toggle = () => { setValue(!value) };
  
  return [value, toggle];
};

function App(){
  const [modal, setModal] = useToggle(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setModal}>Toggle!</button>
      {modal && <span>Toggle!!!!</span>}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what do these scripts do? Why do we need them?

Comment: That is `React` as CDN! You don't need to care about that, you just see the code about yours

Comment: but you didnt change anything, errors are still there

Comment: @heisenberg7584 I've just wrapped `toggle()` with `{}`. did you wrap like it?